# Entity Framework disable relation in two models

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, relationship

I would like to turn off the relationship between the two models.
It's my User model:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

```
namespace EDiary.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public Class Class { get; set; }
        public bool IsTeacher { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And it's class model:

```
namespace EDiary.Models
{
    public class Class
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public User Educator { get; set; }
        public string ClassName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would like the Classes table to have an EducatorId column. I think it should be generated by User Educator {get; set;}. However, this User Educator cannot have any relation to the Class Class in the User model
How can I turn off relations between them?

Comment: "turn off"... I don't know what you mean. Simply remove the properties?

Comment: the first time I've heard that we can turn off/on a relationship, sounds like a very promising feature? From the exception, I think you want to somehow configure a one-one relationship for the 2 entity types. That's all. The problem of your code is the EFCore cannot auto-determine which end is the principal (vs dependent). You need to clearly define that manually by such as `modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().HasOne(e => e.Test2).WithOne(e => e.Test).HasForeignKey("Shadow_Test2_Id")` - that's for FK on `Test` (referencing PK on `Test2`) or `Test2` is principal & `Test` is dependent.

Comment: I added an answer that expressed my thought better.